# any graphic drivers available for windows 10 on Macbook pro(Late 2011)?

Tags: macos, windows-10, macbook-pro, boot-camp

i installed windows 10 on my late 2011 Mac Book pro(Mac OS sierra) with boot camp support software(5.1.5621). its all good so far except for the graphics which i feel is kind of odd. the resolution is definitely not that great. i tried to install next version of boot camp hoping for better results but it says that it is not intended for this model of Mac, i was wondering if i missed installing any drivers that would make windows 10 look much better. anyone have any insights on this issue?

Note: Windows is not activated yet, waiting for my product key. does this got something to do with the appearance?

Comment: Check AMD/Nvidia/Intel's website for Windows 10 compatible drivers

Comment: its got intel drivers installed already.

Comment: So it sounds like it doesn't have a dGPU so that means you have your display drivers installed already.  The version of BootCamp your using, is that the current version, and does it specifically support Windows 10?

Comment: I noticed you had already said you were using BootCamp, so what's your comment, a response to exactly?

Comment: no, im using the latest boot camp whichever supports late 2011 mac models the most latest one doesnt support old mac models

Comment: That isn't what I asked.  Looks like 5.1 doesn't have support for windows 10, so the lack of resolution, is to be expected.

Comment: i dont think it does. there are later versions of boot camp which i cannot install on my mac. so, i was wondering if i can do a work around by installing other drivers.

Comment: You have installed them, you insisted, that made no difference